# Switch next.js page generation mode depending on user

Tags: next.js

Here is my case: I use next.js for a website whose data is hosted in a CRM.
For obvious performance reasons, we are using static site generation which fetches data from the CRM at build time and produces web pages, this part works totally fine.

Now, the CRM offers a preview mode to access unpublished data.
We would like our content writers to be able to use this feature to preview new content in the production website, but it would mean the following:

- The content writer switch to preview mode (I suppose he would get a session cookie specifying he uses the preview mode).
- His requests/page changes should not use statically generated pages, but rather a refreshed server-side rendered version based on his session/cookie.
- The statically generated pages must remain available to the rest of the normal users.

Is something like this possible to achieve?
I didn't find anything on that, but maybe there is another way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js's app directory has a feature called [draft mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/draft-mode) which solves this problem. You can create a [route handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) that enables draft mode on demand.

```js
import { draftMode } from 'next/headers'
 
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  draftMode().enable()
  return new Response('Draft mode is enabled')
}
```

This will set a cookie to enable draft mode. Subsequent requests containing this cookie will trigger Draft Mode changing the behavior for statically generated pages. If you are using the pages router you can use the [preview mode](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/preview-mode) feature.